# Alternative to the lastIndexOf() function

Tags: javascript, indexof

Here is the task at hand:

> "Write a function called `stringLastIndexOf`, which accepts two strings: the first is a word and the second is a single character.
>
> The function should return the last index at which the character exists or -1 if the character is not found.
>
> Do not use the built in `String.lastIndexOf()` function!"

I specifically am struggling with the end requirement, which is to get my function to return the exact position of where the str2 character exists. What could I do to work around not using the `lastindexof` function to do this?

```js
function stringLastIndexOf(str1, str2) {
  var pos = str1.includes(str2, -1);
  if (pos !== true) {
    return -1;
  } else {
    return str2.position();
  }
}
console.log(
  stringLastIndexOf('word', 'w'),
  stringLastIndexOf('pumped', 'f')
  );
```

Comment: loop through the string starting from the back. if you find a match, return whatever index you are at. return `-1` outside of the for loop

Comment: Confused, am i allowed to use `String.prototype.lastIndexOf`? `String.lastIndexOf` doesn't even exist.

Comment: Also, since you are limited to one character in your search: `const stringLastIndexOf = (str, c) => Array.prototype.lastIndexOf.call(str, c);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a simple for loop can solve your problem

```js
function stringLastIndexOf(str1, str2) {
  let index = -1
  for (var i = 0; i < str1.length; i++) {
    if (str1[i] === str2) {
      index = i
    }
  }
  return index
}
console.log(
  stringLastIndexOf('word', 'w'),
  stringLastIndexOf('pumped', 'f')
);
```

Comment: while I understand that this is likely a homework problem from OP, I feel like people reading this answer should know that this implementation would loop over every letter of a string. i.e. if you were using the string 'waffle` with a very large amount of `l` characters (say a million if you must give it a value), but only wanted to look for the `e` character, this would loop through all 1M `l` until getting to the `e` character at the end.

Answer (score 4):

You can loop backward:

```
const aLastIndexOf = (str, ch) => {
    for (let index = str.length - 1; index >= 0; index--) {
        if (str[index] == ch)
            return index;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

An example:

```js
const aLastIndexOf = (str, ch) => {
    for (let index = str.length - 1; index >= 0; index--) {
        if (str[index] == ch)
            return index;
    }
    return -1;
}

console.log(aLastIndexOf("hello", 'h'));
console.log(aLastIndexOf("hello", 'l'));
console.log(aLastIndexOf("hello", 'e'));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you reverse the string first, you can simply use `indexOf`:

```
function stringLastIndexOf(str, c) {
  let pos = str.split("").reverse().join("").indexOf(c);
  return pos == -1 ? -1 : str.length - pos;
}
```

Note that the string is reversed by turning it into an array of characters using `split`, reversing that array, and joining the array into a string again using `join`.

The result of `indexOf` will have to be subtracted from the length of the original string.

Comment: this wouldn't give the correct index from the original string since the output is reversed.

Comment: Egg on my face. Fixed!

Answer (score 0):

We can reverse the string and use `indexOf` also we can keep edge case that passed sting can be empty like this -:

```
function lastIndexOf(str, char){
    return (str.length && (str.length - str.split("").reverse().indexOf(char)-1))
}
```

Comment: you may want to explain how your function would return a number value as newer people may not be accustomed to Javascript's workings with `||` and `&&`.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I see it, betting on ES6, readability and simplicity:

```
const stringLastIndexOf = (str, letter) => {
    let result = -1;
    const strSplitted = str.split('');
    strSplitted.forEach((strLetter, index) => {
        if (strLetter === letter) result = index;
    });
    return result;
};

const test = stringLastIndexOf('test', 't');
console.log(test); // 3
```

*you can try it on your browser's console and play with it*

More about [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) & [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const), [Array.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Comment: Your code would work, not here to argue that, but what is the point of looping over every letter in the string if you are only concerned with the letters at the end? imagine you had the first string as `hello` with 128 "l" characters in total and you are looking for the letter `l`,. why loop through 127 characters needlessly, when starting at the back would get you the answer in 2?

Comment: For (very?) large strings it makes sense yes. Though my writing is dedicated to simplicity and the impact on ressources seems very light. Except if you put a novel as a string! In a professionnal situation, I would prefer your point of view, adding some checks on the string for security and ressources reasons, varying on the actual context.

Comment: If you're betting on simplicity, I'd also make the argument that a regular `for` loop is much simpler to newer people. While I haven't looked this up in some time, for larger strings `for` was much faster than `forEach` (this could have changed depending on how `forEach` is implemented). Agreed, for smaller strings (aka homework problems like this) there's likely very little difference. As developers, however, we have to imagine the most complex use case our code can be used for.